# Não consigo retornar dado do usuario do firebase para exibir no edittext, como faço?

Tags: android, firebase, textview

O Código que estou usando é este:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cotacao);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFarm);

        FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDataBaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuario").child("nome");

        mDataBaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String s = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                Toast.makeText(CotacaoActivity.this, "O que aparece! " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                setTextView(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                setTextView(databaseError.toString());
            }
        });
```

[image: O Firebase está assim.]

Preciso Inserir este nome em um TextView. Só retorna null. Já tentei os mais diversos exemplos e resposta de vocês. Alguém pode ajudar.

Comment: ```.child("usuario").child("nome")``` não existe. Tem que ser ```.child("usuario").child("{ID_DO_USUARIO}").child("nome")```. Pelo menos segundo a estrutura que você postou ali na imagem

Comment: Ok. Então devo colocar a id do usuario e vai mostra o nome? mDataBaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuario").child(userid).child("nome");

Comment: Provavelmente sim

Comment: Verifiquei que o usuário mDataBaseRef está null, mesmo após efetuado o login na activity login (primeira activity). Após fazer login abre-se a tela principal com os menus, e la escolhe qual deve ir, ao entrar em nova activity (terceira ativity) o usuário se apresenta como null.

Comment: Fiz a verificação assim: "Toast.makeText(CotacaoActivity.this, "O que aparece! " + mDataBaseRef, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();"
O retorno de "mDataBaseRef=null". Alguém pode informar porque o que chama o nome do usuário está null? Chamado aqui: mDataBaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuario").child(userId).child("nome");e com isso não exibindo o nome do usuário?

Comment: Já consegui resolver! Foi descuido meu.